# Caching HTTP responses using superagent-cache for different params

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, superagent

I am using superagent-cache for caching responses on Node Express server.
So the request goes like this:

```
myServer.com/api/posts?id=21
```

And the caching works perfectly. Once Node fetches the response from API server, it passes the same data to all the visiting users instead of calling API again and again.

Now the problem is that I want to add user's ID to the request. So the new request becomes:

```
myServer.com/api/posts?id=21&userId=123
```

Now the caching becomes user specific. Superagent takes it as a separate request and fetches it every time for each user. Which is redundant. Is there any way i can tell superagent to avoid `userId` param ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of `superagent-cache`. Glad you're enjoying it!

You can use the [`.pruneQuery` chainable](https://github.com/jpodwys/superagent-cache#prunequeryparams) to execute a query with a given param but cache it without that param as part of the generated key.

Your new code should look something like this:

```
superagent
  .get('myServer.com/api/posts')
  .query({id: id, userId: userId})
  .pruneQuery(['userId'])
  .end(function (error, response){
    // handle response
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! I'll try this out. Meanwhile I am experiencing this error `cache-module: .set() failed for cache of type cache-module { name: 'CacheModuleSetException',`. It is showing up in PM2 console. Any Ideas ?

Comment: What version of superagent-cache are you pinned to? And under what circumstances is it happening?

Comment: I'm using `1.7.2` for superagent and `^1.4.1` for superagent-cache. It's happening on the node-server randomly when trying to cache API response.

Comment: That's not good! Is it breaking your application, or just not caching now and then? Can you try using 1.6.1 for superagent?

Comment: It's not breaking the app. I guess not caching now and then. I'll surely try out the 1.6.1 version.